# Can I travel multiple one-way back-and-forth flights to the same destinations on one day?

Tags: loyalty-programs, british-airways, malaysia-airlines

Flying between KUL and PEN on Malaysia in Business yield 40 British Airways Executive Club Tier Points, and costs only £50-55, which is a very attractive £1.25-1.38 per Tier Point.

If I book multiple one-way flights on the same day, between the two destinations, will I be allowed to fly?

For example:

- MH1140 KUL-PEN 11:25-12:10
- MH1149 PEN-KUL 15:30-16:25
- MH1162 KUL-PEN 19:30-20:25
- MH1165 PEN-KUL 20:55-21:50

Comment: Why shouldn't you?

Comment: Well, trying to book roundtrips the price jumps to £219, so they might see it negatively.

Comment: Ah, for the days of the [baht runs](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trip-reports/179602-baht-run-thailand-84-flights-7-days.html)!

Comment: @gberger One-way Business Flex - 668 MYR, Roundtrip Business Flex - 2x 609 MYR. I don't see any price jumpm, I see the opposite.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Southwest, for instance, doesn’t allow multiple flights to the same city on the same day. This probably depends on the airline.

Comment: The points may only cost 1.25, but how much is your time worth?

Comment: Hmm... after 10 days of this exciting itinerary, you get to Gold for approximately £2,000.

Comment: This reminds me of https://thepointsguy.com/2015/10/37-rental-cars-in-2-days/ so much.

Comment: @Kevin Bring a laptop, now you've got an office with a great view.

Answer (score 30):

Yes.  There is the possibility you'll be questioned as to your motives, but in the end they're all domestic flights, so it's down to you and the airline for the transaction, and they've sold you the tickets.

Of course, the Earth might not thank you ;)

I know of a role here in Sydney which requires employees (non-airline) to fly 6 flights in a day, with flights 2, 4 and 6 returning to the same city.  It's a regular feature for people on the team, and they're never prevented/questioned about it, except by the crew who can start to recognise them :)

Comment: What sort of job is that?  Unless it involves doing something while in flight I'm having a hard time believing it wouldn't be more efficient to have multiple part timers working across the various locations.

Comment: @DanNeely it's doing something while in flight, yes.

Comment: @DanNeely - they're [totally not Air Marshals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOjQ0qfGQvU)

Comment: Sounds like something just a bit dodgy, be real curious to know if the technique could be implemented by OP to gain value from the flights and the voyager miles as he enjoys flying so much and has free time.

Comment: Don't leave us hanging, @DanNeely !

Comment: Assuming by "the Earth" you mean CO2 emissions, would the additional marginal weight of a person really increase fuel consumption all that much?

Comment: Of course @BruceWayne figured it out...

Comment: @MarchHo nope, but that's the logical fallacy - we're all required to 'do our part' ;) He's not the only mile runner out there

Comment: @MarchHo: Consider if that additional person was the tipping point to the airline deciding to put an extra flight in due to demand...

Answer (score 22):

Yes. The airline is a business, they are happy to receive your repeat custom.

Your concern should be whether this is feasible: if the same aircraft is used to operate all flights, then one flight delayed will not impact the rest of your itinerary, because the subsequent flights will also be delayed. (This is called a "back-to-back" in mileage running terms.) If different aircraft are used, then one delay could scupper the rest of your itinerary.

The second problem is that the British Airways Executive Club has difficulty understanding flying the same route on the same day multiple times; *i.e.*, you may only end up with one set of tier points. So keep your boarding passes as evidence you flew multiple times and retroclaim if needs be.

Finally be aware that if this fare books into "I" class, it will earn zero Avios and zero TP on BAEC. If it books into "Z", you are okay.

Enjoy your trip.